# how to drag an td element and drop it in another td element in a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making an UI from which I have some static 'td' element and a table in which I have some 'td' element.Now I want to drag the static 'td' element and drop it and replace the existing 'td' element in it. I want to know which 'td' is replaced and by which 'td' it is replaced so I could update my database via 'PHP'.

This is code I have been using for drag and drop but not useful:

```js
$("#fool td").draggable({
            revert: "invalid"
            // start: function(ev, ui){ ui.helper.width($(this).width()); }
        });

        $('#cool').droppable({
            accept : "#fool td",
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            greedy : true,
            hoverClass: 'highlight',
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                alert('hi');
            //$(this).innerHTML($(ui.draggable));
                $(ui.droppable).replaceWith("<div>Some content</div>");
            }
        });
```

My HTML code for static 'td' is:

```html
<div id="fool"><table id="draggable"><tr><td style="background-color:blue">english</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color:yellow">hindi</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color:green">maths</td></tr><tr><td style="background-color:white">physics</td></tr></table></div>
<div id="cool"><table>---- all td elemenet ------</table></div>
```

Where inside 'cool' `div` I am generating a dynamic table after that I want drag and drop on that cool table.

Comment: Is that droppable plugin also replacing the td you want to replace? Or is it just inserting the td you're dragging? Also please add which library you're using for the dragging and dropping.

Comment: yes it should replace the 'td' at drop andi should know that what is getting replaced with what  i am using jquery-ui library

Answer (score 0):

As i think you need to swap two TD so,

You can use Zepto plugin as its provide all your swapping information.
refer : http://james2doyle.github.io/zepto-dragswap/

Comment: no actually i dont want swapping the 'td' that is dragged and should replace a 'td' and that should be deleted

Comment: even if swapping is used can i do it wothout any plugin

Comment: yes i tried it its working for <li> but not for <Td> element can you tell me why??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
1. Include jQuery library and TableDnD.js

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablednd.0.7.min.js"></script>

2. Call the plugin

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {



    // Initialise the first table (as before)

    $("#table-1").tableDnD();





    });

    </script>

3. Markup

    <table id="table-1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">

        <tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>One</td><td>some text</td></tr>

        <tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Two</td><td>some text</td></tr>

        <tr id="3"><td>3</td><td>Three</td><td>some text</td></tr>

        <tr id="4"><td>4</td><td>Four</td><td>some text</td></tr>

        <tr id="5"><td>5</td><td>Five</td><td>some text</td></tr>

    <tr id="6"><td>6</td><td>Six</td><td>some text</td></tr>

    </table>
```

for info [click here....](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Drag-Drop-Table-Plugin-with-jQuery-TableDnD.html)